# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox click a link

Tags: perl

I have this following line

```
$agent->follow_link( xpath => '//a[text() = "123456"]' );
```

I am trying to click a link that has a value in `<a href="alwaysdifferenthere">123456</a>`

The code above doesn't click a link. I am doing this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
...
$mech->follow_link( tag => 'a', text => '123456' );
```